# Ошибка XCode при сборке проекта. Cannot find type 'AppDelegate' in scope

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, swift4

Ошибка появляется в файле PushNotification.swift. Публикую чась кода в этом файле

```html
import UserNotifications

var PushNotificationPluginToken = ""
let PushNotificationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "pluginPushNotificationQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
let PushNotificationSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

@objc(AppDelegate) extension AppDelegate {   Ошибка: Cannot find type 'AppDelegate' in scope     
  open override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    PushNotificationPluginToken = token
    PushNotificationSemaphore.signal()
  }
```

Есть в проекте файл AppDelegate.h

```html
/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Харибол Экадаши
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate : CDVAppDelegate {}

@end
```

А также AppDelegate.m

```html
/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Харибол Экадаши
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Я пытаюсь запустить проект в виртуальной машине. Использую cordova. Мои данные оборудования.

- ОС - Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5
- XCode - 12.4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста решить этот вопрос. Если нужны еще какие-то данные для большего понимания, напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Структуру проекта лучше покажите, может у вас эти файлы по разным модулям разбросаны.

Comment: подскажите. структуру показать, которая в xcode отображается?

Comment: Да, та что слева древовидная.

Comment: Добавил структуру проекта в конец описания вопроса.

Comment: Проверьте что оба к одному таргету относятся (Target Membership справа при выборе файла) и вот еще: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38721992/5479247

Comment: Простите, пожалуйста я в Swift практически ноль. Можете поподробнее объяснить ответ.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, куда мне нужно добавить этот код: #import "AppDelegate.h"

Comment: В bridging header файл, он буквально так и называется. Xcode 12 уже староват, обновиться до хотя бы 13 никак?

Comment: Добавил код в файл. Ушла ошибка. Большое спасибо! Эмулятор не запустился, возникла новая ошибка

Comment: `Details

The request to open "haribol.ekadashi.app" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
Domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain
Code: 3
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = OperationFailed;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)
Timestamp: 2022-11-17T15:01:29+02:00`

Comment: Буду гуглить) Надеюсь найду ответ на решение ошибки! Спасибо)